# Is there an app that can automatically separate scenes/clips from a video file and export them?

Tags: video, linux, automation, programming, clipping

I am looking to parse a collection downloaded YouTube videos that are actually compilations containing clips from several different videos all over the web. I would like for this program to automatically separate the individual scenes/clips from a given video file and export them as each individual video files into a folder.

I have done hours upon hours of searching and tried different programs on my Linux system but to no avail any luck at all with anything that can do this fairly simple task.

It would be really nice to have some program that did this via the command line.

Thank you so very much for your time and expertise.

Answer (score 1):

Most professional quality video editing software has this kind of functionality.  You can take a look at [DaVinci Resolve](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/support/download/09b6a86402cd4892b29b33da6eb8075e/Linux), which is available for free on Linux.  [This article](https://www.premiumbeat.com/blog/speed-color-workflow-using-scene-cut-detection/) has more details about how to do it, but "Scene Cut Detection" is the name of the feature you are looking for and it's available when right clicking on a video file.